# Django application run without command line like php web application

Tags: django, windows, apache, django-runserver

I want to launch Django application without giving command "python manage.py runserver".
Like how php works, when hit the index file it will launch the application but in django/python i didn't find any way to do that in windows OS except run the project from command line which is cautious for robust application.

Please let me know/suggest any idea about if it is possible for windows or not??

Comment: you do need a server for "running" php files. the servers like XAMPP need to be explicitly started before your php files can be interpreted.
similarly with django, iirc, you are starting the server by running the command `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: The question is why you wanna do it ? On local that is the way to do it by using django server but on production you would do it similar to php having a frontend server (apache or nginx) and application server (gunicorn running on top of supervisor for example)

Comment: I got the answer Thanks for your valuable reply. And i want to make clear myself that from the very begining of my development journey i have been working with php and now while switching to python and django , i just search the flavor of the running application in Django end like Laravel/Php.
Just out of curiosity,  i find a possible way to do that.